# How do I know if my motherboard is dead?

Tags: creality-cr-10, lcd-screen

I have an Ender CR-10 which I recently installed a clone of a BLTouch on. It all worked fine and printed well but once when I started the printer all the pixels on the LCD were white. Then when I started the 4th time the LCD just went all black and I got no power to it. I also have a Raspberry Pi 4B which I tried connecting to the printer but it couldn't anymore.

Do I need to get a new motherboard or is there anything I can do to see where the error is so I can fix it?

*I havent measured any voltage yet, I'll have to do that when I have some spare time...*

Comment: Does the printer power up without the Raspberry Pi? Have you tried disconnecting the LCD and powering it on?

Comment: yes, i also removed the bl-touch from the printer and reconnected everything like it is stock. The raspberry pi doesnt do anything right now because it wont connect to the printer.

Comment: I just realise that i missunderstood that question, it doesnt work whatever i do